# How do I filter column to only show text values of a certain length?

Tags: powerbi, dax, alpha

I have a column in my dataset that is freeform and I need to filter or count the rows that only have alpha characters with a length of 5. I need to be able to do so using dax to create a new measure(s).

Sample Data (Reporting 5):

- 999999999
- BLANK GUEST
- CODED
- 44817
- 13531
- VGPTRE
- .

I've tried queries using LEN, IF(CONTAINS and other similar functions, but I cannot get the desired results, almost everything results in errors.

Answer (score 0):

Write a measure in DAX

```
Measure = COUNTROWS(CALCULATETABLE(data, FILTER(data, LEN((Data[Data])) = 5 && NOT(CONTAINSSTRING((Data[Data]), "0") || CONTAINSSTRING((Data[Data]),"1") || CONTAINSSTRING((Data[Data]),"2") || CONTAINSSTRING((Data[Data]),"3") || CONTAINSSTRING((Data[Data]),"4") || CONTAINSSTRING((Data[Data]),"5") || CONTAINSSTRING((Data[Data]),"6") || CONTAINSSTRING((Data[Data]),"7") || CONTAINSSTRING((Data[Data]),"8") || CONTAINSSTRING((Data[Data]),"9")))))
```

[image]